# Limit number of characters in textField

Tags: swift, uitextfield

Hi all I'm using the code below to limit the amount of characters in a textfield. It works fine when typing but when I paste or take the string from another var it shows the whole txt. when I click it it again it removes the extra characters. is there a way to do this so when a text is pasted in it only shows the amount I specify?

```
import UIKit

private var maxLengths = [UITextField: Int]()

extension UITextField {

@IBInspectable var maxLength: Int {

  get {

      guard let length = maxLengths[self] 
         else {
            return Int.max
  }
  return length
 }
  set {
  maxLengths[self] = newValue
  addTarget(
     self,
     action: #selector(limitLength),
     for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged
  )
  }
}
func limitLength(textField: UITextField) {
guard let prospectiveText = textField.text,
    prospectiveText.characters.count > maxLength
else {
    return
}

 let selection = selectedTextRange
 let maxCharIndex = prospectiveText.index(prospectiveText.startIndex, offsetBy: maxLength)
 text = prospectiveText.substring(to: maxCharIndex)
selectedTextRange = selection
}
}
```

method

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let currentText = (textField.text as NSString?) ?? NSString()
    let currentCharacterCount = currentText.length
    if range.length + range.location > currentCharacterCount {
        return false
    }
    let newLength = currentText.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string).characters.count
    return newLength <= 3

}
```

The textField is called regNumber.text

Comment: Where is your implementation of the `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)` delegate method?

Comment: I have added this function in, I'm not sure if i have to call it somewhere?

Comment: Have you set the text field's delegate ? otherwise `UITextFieldDelegate` methods you implement wouldn't be invoked.

Comment: I have set the delegate